# Is there an open / established categorization / list of terms / concepts and synonyms for mathematics?

Tags: terminology, definition, convention

I am currently thinking about how to bundle some of the efforts of students to get / create good educational material. One idea of this little project ([wiki-ed](https://github.com/MartinThoma/wiki-ed) - still in the very early phase) is to add machine-readable meta information to content which states what the material (e.g. lecture notes) are teaching and which skills they require. Having a lot of educational material with this kind of meta-data should allow students to search for what they are interested in and find the minimum material they need to know to understand it.

However, stating what is required and what is taught is difficult, as one might have different names. For example:

1. natural numbers
2. Natural numbers
3. Natural Numbers
4. set of natural numbers
5. N
6. $\mathbb{N}$

So there is need for a way to look for one way to describe it. I think I have read something like this for American / British math students.

Is there such a freely available list which defines such concepts and gives them names?

Comment: I'm not too sure if this is really suitable here. Another site where I thought this might fit is http://academia.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You seem that think that this is a good idea...

Comment: You could have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_mathematics_topics

Comment: @Jonas I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Could somebody who downvoted this please explain why?

Answer (score 1):

What I was looking for is [Mathematics Subject Classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_Subject_Classification):

> The Mathematics Subject Classification (MSC) is an alphanumerical classification scheme collaboratively produced by staff of, and based on the coverage of, the two major mathematical reviewing databases, Mathematical Reviews and Zentralblatt MATH. It is used by many mathematics journals, which ask authors of research papers and expository articles to list subject codes from the Mathematics Subject Classification in their papers. The current version is MSC2010.

One can download it here: http://www.ams.org/msc/msc2010.html

It only defines different sub-fields of mathematics, but not concepts as far as I can see. However, this was what I was looking for when I wrote "American / British math students".

So if you know a similar categorization for concepts / terminology, I would still be happy to read about it.

Comment: Well, why didn't you say so?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I don't understand the question. I was looking for this categorization, but I only had it very vaguely in mind. Don't you know it when you search for a word? So if your question is why I didn't say the word I was looking for, then I have  to give the obvious answer that I was not remembering it.

Comment: If I wanted a list of all the different topics and subtopics of Mathematics, it would never have occurred to me to ask for an ontology, let alone an open ontology. Most of us do not have that phrase in our working vocabulary. I would have tried to use words people might understand.

Comment: OK, with your edit, it now appears that you weren't looking for a list of topics, but a list of concepts. So that means that your answer isn't a satisfactory answer. So I suggest you unaccept it. This may encourage some people who don't look at questions that have accepted answers, to look at it. (But I still recommend ditching the "ontology" bit, and going for a more accessible title)

Comment: OK, you seem to be carrying out my suggestions while I'm still typing them. Cool.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh, ok. I thought that was the most precise title for the question. How would you phrase it? (I've added "open" because I had http://sciencewise.info/ontology/ in mind, which seems not to be "free to use")

Comment: @GerryMyerson Judging from your reputation, you know how the math.SE community works. Of course I value your feedback and try to improve my answers. I'm sorry when the question is a bit more "confused" / bad phrased than it should be, but I didn't know how to ask it in a better way.